# 2 Message Queues? A good idea within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1)  Is it good design to have TWO message queues. The rational is that Rabbit_MQ has a built in method for creating worker_queues (they even give sample code). Resque_Job uses redis, and seems to be the accepted method of having ‘delayed jobs’ with Rails.

a.  What I like about RabbitMQ: It has round-robin tasking  abilities (so all threats get tasked) , and guarantees work will not be removed from a QUEUE without a message acknowledgement.
b.  Resque seems to primary suggested solution for launching delayed_jobs within Rails.

Comment: You can have as many queues as needed. No one size fits all.

Comment: See also [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job). As long as your server can handle the queue processing, I don't see why it should be a problem.